# Django Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'videofile'

Tags: python, django

I am following [this](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-create-a-video-uploader-with-Python-in-Django.php) tutorial to create a video uploader in my Django project and have run into this error:

..src/video/views.py", line 9, in showvideo
    videofile= lastvideo.videofile
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'videofile'

I'm sure I am missing something obvious and have been looking for the answer for a while now. Would be grateful for any help.

```
views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import VideoUpload
from .forms import VideoForm

def showvideo(request):

    lastvideo= VideoUpload.objects.last()

    videofile= lastvideo.videofile


    form= VideoForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()


    context= {'videofile': videofile,
              'form': form
              }


    return render(request, 'video.html', context)
```

```
forms.py

from django import forms
from .models import VideoUpload


class VideoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = VideoUpload
        fields = ["name", "videofile"]
```

```
models.py

from django.db import models

class VideoUpload(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    videofile= models.FileField(upload_to='videos/', null=True, verbose_name="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ": " + str(self.videofile)
```

```
from django.conf import settings 
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from video.views import (
    showvideo,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('showvideo', showvideo, name='showvideo'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
 urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
 urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

FYI I updated the name of the model to 'VideoUpload' vs the tutorial.

Comment: Your **`VideoUpload`** model doesn't have at least one instance in Database, that's why this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no last_video record in your database. To prevent this from erroring out in such and instance, you could change the line: `videofile= lastvideo.videofile` into

```
videofile = lastvideo.videofile if lastvideo else None
```

This will prevent an error from being thrown. Alternatively you could put the whole bit in a try/except block.